# SparkFun Power Driver Shield Kit for controlling 60 V input

Tags: voltage, mosfet, mosfet-driver, sparkfun

I just bought [SparkFun Power Driver Shield Kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10618). I read in the specifications that it was possible to control up to 60 V using PWM. I have got a project where I need to control 60 V with the PWM so I bought this card but got a bit confused when I got it. I thought it simply would be possible to connect my 60 V output into the card and controlling the output with PWM. but I got confused where it says 12 V and 5 V.

Is it not possible to use higher voltage then 12 V with the card? My idea was to use it basically as a dimmer, controlling voltage between 0 - 60 V with the help of PWM.

Did I misunderstand something about the concept?

Comment: What specifications? Was there a manual?

Comment: That kit is not likely to work for your purposes without some modification. What is the proposed load running at 60V?

Comment: no manual unfortunately. it seems like the RFP30N06LE MOSFETS, at least would be able to handle what I want: "Maximum Drain-Source Voltage |Vds|: 60 V"
https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=19587

The load will be around 5w

Comment: Ask Sparkfun. Try asking the manufacturer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "5V" and "12V" notation refers to using a standard PC power supply to run the project, via the 24-pin ATX connector. See the schematic [here](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/PowerDriver-Shield-v13.pdf).

If you omit D1, LED1 and LED2 from your assembly, you can apply whatever voltage you like to the "5V" and "12V" pins of the 24-pin ATX connector.

Comment: thanks. So I basically put a solid wire over the holes where the 1N4001(D1) and the LED1 and LED2 is supposed to be right?

Comment: No, just leave those holes unpopulated. You want an open circuit, not a short circuit. You'll have to power your Arduino separately.